# Waiting for a callback-based function within a stack of Promises

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, q

From reading around and trial and error, I can't work out the best way to integrate a third-party async, callback-based function into a Promises workflow. Hoping for some pointers.

I'm building a dashboard using Google Charts and a Python-based API. I'm trying to integrate Google Spreadsheets data using [Goog's Query approach](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries#Sending_a_Query):

```
// Create a new Query object      
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com?key=123AB&...', opts);    

// Send the query with a callback function.
query.send(handleQueryResponse);

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  // Called when the query response is returned.
  ...
}
```

For each chart, I'm trying to create a stack of Promises using `Q.js`:

```
// Streamlined example
Q.fcall(collectData)
.then(drawChartUsingData)
.done();
```

The problem is that the call to `query.send()` within `collectData` is asyncronous and so the result isn't saved to the window by the time I call `drawChartUsingData`. I need the next Promise in the chain to wait for the callback to finish. I'm not waiting on the return value to be passed as I'm writing that to a global variable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

*PS. I'm a Python guy coming to terms with JS for the frontend, so please excuse any basic errors or lack of appreciation for JS best practice.*

Comment: I don't understand how the two fragments are related. Can you create a single, simple, coherent example?

Comment: Is the first chunk of code, the one that creates `query`, in the body of `collectData`? If so, probably want to have `collectData` return a promise that gets resolved by `handleQueryResponse` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises